# Convert Boolean to generic type

Tags: vb.net, boolean, generics

In VB.NET 2010, how to return a boolean value as generic type without compile warning?

thanks!
Michael

Comment: 1. show the code. 2. Show the exact compiler warning and indicate the line where it happens. Otherwise we can't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn Options Strict Off

Answer (score 0):

generic, you mean this?

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(blah(True).ToString)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Function blah(Of t)(ByVal typ As t) As T
    Return typ
End Function
```